# Zenoss with Apache Rewrite subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, zenoss

I'm trying to set up Zenoss to work with https://server/zenoss instead of https://server.  Here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/zenoss($|/.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot/zenoss$1 [L,P]
```

This way doesn't work.  I get:

> Site error
>
> An error was encountered while publishing this resource. The requested resource does not exist.
>   Please click here to return to the Zenoss dashboard

The url for "Please click here to return to the Zenoss dashboard" points to https://server/zport/dmd

However, it does work if I do it the standard Zenoss/Plone/Zope way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

... it works great.

According to [this article](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/ProxyApacheToZope), it seems like the first way should work.  I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra `zenoss` in your first RewriteRule (and you're also doubling up on slashes).  It reads:

```
RewriteRule ^/zenoss($|/.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot/zenoss$1 [L,P]
```

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/zenoss($|/.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting redirected to https://server/zport/dmd with that rule.

Comment: You aren't trying to do this in a .htaccess, are you?  If not, fire up some rewrite logging and figure out what's going in and what's coming out of the RewriteRule.

Comment: No, I'm putting it in the apache configuration file.  The only thing I can see in the Apache error logs is:  [Mon May 23 11:40:17 2011] [error] [client 10.8.1.40] File does not exist: /var/www/html/zenoss
[Mon May 23 11:40:17 2011] [error] [client 10.8.1.40] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico

Comment: How about: `RewriteRule ^/zenoss($|/.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]`.  If this doesn't work, either turn on RewriteLog, or do a manual request (e.g. `links 'http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/server:443/VirtualHostRoot/'`).

Comment: That rewrite rule didn't work either. I get the same error.  I don't know how to turn on RewriteLog.  The manual request works directly on the server.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog